# How to download anything from the webview in electron js?

Tags: javascript, browser, electron

const { BrowserWindow, app, ipcMain, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

function MainUI() {
let ui = new BrowserWindow({
width: 1280,
height: 720,
title: "Browsify",
autoHideMenuBar: true,
// transparent: true,
// frame: false,
titleBarStyle: "hidden",
titleBarOverlay: {
color: '#303030',
symbolColor: 'white',
height: 40,
},
webPreferences: {
nodeIntegration: true,
contextIsolation: false,
webSecurity: true,
webviewTag: true,
devTools: true,
safeDialogs: true,
safeDialogsMessage: true,
allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
}
});
ui.loadFile('./index.html');
// ipcRenderer.send(ui.webContents.getURL());
// ui.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(MainUI);

I didn't tried anything yet for this issue because I really don't know what to do and how to solve this problem...

Comment: I just want to make a web browser using electron js. Its also working properly but it is unable to download anything from the webview in electron js. Anyone please help me solving this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.